# Converting raw thesaurus data into nice JSON file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to improve my dirty data wrangling code into something nice, readable & reliable.

I believe I've done fairly well here, although maybe I should have some docstrings on my functions. Still, I believe it's fairly readable without them.

I'd love some feedback on ways to improve! This script parses raw data from [Gray Ward's fantastic public-domain thesaurus](ftp://svr-ftp.eng.cam.ac.uk/pub/comp.speech/dictionaries/moby/) into a more readable JSON file.

```
import sys
import os
import json

# Parses Grady Ward's public-domain thesaurus, available at
# ftp://svr-ftp.eng.cam.ac.uk/pub/comp.speech/dictionaries/moby/

def main():
    database = {}

    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print("Usage: make_database <input filename> <ouput filename>")
        sys.exit(1)

    filename = sys.argv[1]

    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        print(f"File {filename} doesn't exist.")
        sys.exit(1)

    # Read file into database
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        try:
            parse_file(file, database)
            print("Finished reading the file.")
        except Exception as err:
            print(f"Failed to read file {filename} with error {err}")
            sys.exit(1)

    # Write database to output file as JSON
    output_filename = sys.argv[2]
    with open(output_filename, "w+") as file:
        try:
            data = json.dumps(database)
            file.write(data)
            print(f"Finished writing to file {output_filename}")
        except Exception as err:
            print(f"Failed to read write to file {output_filename} with error {err}")
            sys.exit(1)

def parse_file(file, database):
    for line in file:
        (word, thesaurus) = parse_line(line)
        database[word] = thesaurus

def parse_line(line):
    words = line.strip().split(",")
    return (words[0], words[1:])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm still a student -- I'm trying to improve my code readability & maintainability.

It is a commandline utility that can be called like:

```
make_database <input filename> <output filename>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Welcome to Code Review!

The current code looks clean enough. Since it will be a command line utility, I'd suggest taking up the [`argparse`](https://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/argparse) or [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/5/). `argparse` is a python inbuilt module, so your end package will not have a dependency other than the dictionary files.

The `json` package provide the method [`json.dump`](https://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/json#json.dump) which can write directly to a file. No need to have extra memory consumption.

Instead of using `print` statements, I'd go with `logging` builtin module with possibly multiple handlers, if you want to stream logs to console or file etc.

Answer (score 1):

A few more short comments:

1. I find a script easier to read if all necessary functions are defined before being called. This would mean moving `parse_file` and `parse_line` above `main`.
2. When returning a tuple, or using tuple assignment, you don't need parenthesis:

   ```
   def f(x):
       return x, 2*x

   a, a2 = f(2)
   ```
3. Your `parse_file` function could be slightly shortened using `map`:

   ```
   def parse_file(file, database):
       for word, thesaurus in map(parse_line, file):
           database[word] = thesaurus
   ```
4. In `parse_line` you could use [extended tuple unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) to give the parts more meaningful names:

   ```
   def parse_line(line):
       word, *thesaurus = line.strip().split(",")
       return word, thesaurus
   ```
5. There is no need to define `database` if the number of arguments is not enough. I would move the line to where it is first needed. Or, even better, let `parse_file` return a dictionary, since you never update an existing dictionary (and even if you did, you could just call `dict.update` with that returned dictionary):

   ```
   def main():
       ...
       try:
           database = parse_file(filename)
           ...
       ...

   def parse_file(file):
       return dict(map(parse_line, file))
   ```